# Increment numbers inside a string

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm putting together a long list of users where the user names have the format `user001`, `user002` etc. To each user there is an e-mail address with the format `user.001@example.com`, `user.002@example.com`.

Now I would like to use the function in Excel that allows you to "drag-and-click" copy cells downward and increases the number by one for every cell when I'm going to enter the e-mail addresses. However, that only seems to work if the number is last in the string.

What I get now is just copies of `user.001@example.com`. Is there someway to make the number 001 increment even though it is inside a string or do I have to edit it all manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can work around with something like that:

```
A1: "user"
B1: 1
C1: "@example.com"
D1: =$A$1&TEXT(B1,"000")&$C$1
```

[Edit: This applies for the english version of Excel, otherwise the last line should read `=$A$1&TEXT(B1;"000")&$C$1`, note the semicolon instead of a comma. Thanks @Kevin for clarifiying this point.]

Then you can drag-and-click column B and D, where D will look like

```
user001@example.com
user002@example.com
user003@example.com
user004@example.com
user005@example.com
...
```

Comment: Unfortunally, the excel sheet is homegrown, heavily macroed and locked down and I don't have access to the password. If there is no way to do it without manipulating I'll just have to do it manually.

Comment: Can't you create the list in a separate excel sheet and copy&paste it into the original one?

Comment: Yes, trying that. Unfortunally, the formula given does not work. I get an error and then it marks the area inside the TEXT function.

Comment: I changed the format specifier in my answer. Now it should also work in Excel 2010 according to http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/text.php. I can only test in LibreOffice.

Comment: Still not working but I figured it out. There should be a semicolon, not a comma. TEXT(B1;"00#") works.

Comment: Strange, completely in contrast to the cited helpfile... but essentially it works.

Comment: Semicolon is generally used in none english versions of Excel, english language versions use a comma.
If this answer answered your question you should +1 the answer and mark it as an answer so that others dont come along and try to answer it again.

Answer (score 3):

Better use the below. This doesn't require to create a extra column with incremental values.
If you follow the previous extra column(A1) then finally you have to remove that column and created values to be Copy & pasted (as values) again.

```
="user"&TEXT(ROW(), "000")&"@example.com"

="user"&TEXT(ROW()+100, "000")&"@example.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you use two columns, like this:

```
A1: user001
B1: =A1&"@example.com"
```

When you drag the two columns down, the string in column B will increase as you describe.

Not knowing what the limitation are on your sheet, I don't know if you can do this.

You could also try using an equation like this

```
A1: ="user"&COLUMN(A1)&"@example.com"
```

To get the correct number of 0s , you could use the format parameter in the TEXT(value, format_text) function.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something related to this, see what I found:

```
=LEFT(A835,3)+1&"Ay"
```

If you have a text or serial or reference number like this

> 942Ay

And you don't want to copy and paste again and again, you can use above method
by using the `LEFT` function, `&` and add 1 and then your text, whatever it is.
You can also continue or add more text by using the `&` key without spaces and without an apostrophe.